# Dagger 2 scope annotation on the "provides" method or on the injected class

Tags: java, scope, annotations, singleton, dagger-2

I see in the Dagger 2 examples some people use `@Singleton` on the module's provisioning methods but also on the class that is provided.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Navigator providesNavigator(ActivityNavigator activityNavigator) {
    return activityNavigator;
}
```

vs

```
@Singleton
public class ActivityNavigator extends Navigator {}
```

What's the difference of both placements? Should be used both of them or one of them is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Singleton
public class ActivityNavigator extends Navigator {}
```

Will be used with constructor injection, that is if dagger creates the object for you.

This said, if you have the above annotation *and* make use of constructor injection, like in the following...

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Navigator providesNavigator(ActivityNavigator activityNavigator) {
    return activityNavigator;
}
```

Dagger will create (and keep) the `ActivityNavigator` instance as a `@Singleton` within the component. It will then provide you with this singleton instance, and you return it as a `Navigator`, also a singleton. Wherever you use this component, if you require a `ActivityNavigator` or `Navigator` will be used.

In your case, this is redundant. If you plan on using the interface `Navigator`, and not the implementation, there is no need that the same object should or would be created a second time. It is probably still a safe bet to keep it, since not using the same "singleton" in different parts of your application is often a bug that could be avoided this way.

---

The annotation *would* be needed for something like the following:

```
@Singleton
public class ActivityNavigator extends Navigator implements SomeThingElse {}
```

Whatever the reason, now you have one object possibly providing 2 different implementations. If you want to reuse always the same object, you have to make sure it only gets created *once*. If you wouldn't provide the annotation for constructor injection this object would be created twice. But since you do, both `Navigator` and `SomeThingElse` would return the same object.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Navigator providesNavigator(ActivityNavigator activityNavigator) {
    return activityNavigator; // singleton ActivityNavigator!
}

@Provides
@Singleton
SomeThingElse providesSomethingElse(ActivityNavigator activityNavigator) {
    return activityNavigator; // the same ActivityNavigator!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should use this:

```
@Singleton
public class ActivityNavigator extends Navigator {}
```

You need provide for non simple injections. For example you can't annotate an interface and even if you could how should dagger know which implemetation you want for that interface?.

Here is a quote from the official site.

> By default, Dagger satisfies each dependency by constructing an
>   instance of the requested type as described above. When you request a
>   CoffeeMaker, it'll obtain one by calling new CoffeeMaker() and setting
>   its injectable fields.
>
> But @Inject doesn't work everywhere:
>
> **Interfaces can't be constructed.**
>
> **Third-party classes can't be annotated.**
>
> **Configurable objects must be configured!**
>
> For these cases where @Inject is insufficient or awkward, use an > @Provides-annotated
>   method to satisfy a dependency. The method's return type defines which
>   dependency it satisfies.